Graph shrinks after resize() when pointRadius is positive
I encountered an issue where the size of the chart changes unexpectedly when the pointRadius of a dataset is modified. Here's a minimal explanation of the behavior:

Initial state: I initialize a chart with no points (all pointRadius values set to 0). The chart correctly occupies the full available space within its container.
Updating pointRadius: If I update at least one pointRadius to a positive value and call chart.update(), the chart behaves as expected—the point is displayed correctly, and the chart's size does not change. But...
If a chart.resize() is triggered (e.g., due to a window resize event, or directly using the console), the chart shrinks. The reduction in chart size seems proportional to the largest pointRadius in the dataset.
Resetting pointRadius: If I set all pointRadius values back to 0, followed by a chart.update() and chart.resize(), the chart regains its original size.

This behavior is problematic, as the chart size should not depend on the pointRadius values. I believe this could be an issue with how the chart's dimensions are calculated during resizing when points are present.
Could this be a bug? Or is there a way to ensure the chart maintains its size regardless of pointRadius?
Thank you for your help!

Please provide a [mre]. We can't say anything without seeing your code. We have no idea what you have done, have you included the canvas in a div, have you set maintainAspectRatio: false, how are your scales set up, etc.
